# Set-AzureRmResourceGroup : 'resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern '^[-\w\._\(\)]+$'

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Running this below and can't seem to get the collection correct to pass into the ForEach loop, even though it returns the names I want.
$RGInfo returns as expected.  But when I pass it into the loop to Set-AzureRmResourceGroup, it errors as below

```
PS H:\> $rginfo

ResourceGroupName   
-----------------   
rg-crp-d365-bp-n    
rg-crp-d365-dev1-n  
rg-crp-d365-dev2-n  
rg-crp-d365-upgrad-n

$RGInfo = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "RG-CRP-D365*" } | Select-Object ResourceGroupName

ForEach ($RGName in $RGInfo) {
    If ($RGName.Tags -eq $null) { 
        Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Tag @{BUSINESS_UNIT="CRP"; COST_CENTER="6435" }       
    }
}
```

Know why I keep getting the below?  There are four RG's so the ForEach loop is functional.

> Set-AzureRmResourceGroup : 'resourceGroupName' does not match expected
>   pattern '^[-\w._()]+$'. At line:7 char:2
>   +  Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Tag @{BUSINESS_ ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmResourceGroup], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetA
>   zureResourceGroupCmdlet   Set-AzureRmResourceGroup :
>   'resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern '^[-\w._()]+$'.
>   At line:7 char:2
>   +  Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Tag @{BUSINESS_ ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmResourceGroup], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetA
>   zureResourceGroupCmdlet   Set-AzureRmResourceGroup :
>   'resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern '^[-\w._()]+$'.
>   At line:7 char:2
>   +  Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Tag @{BUSINESS_ ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmResourceGroup], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetA
>   zureResourceGroupCmdlet   Set-AzureRmResourceGroup :
>   'resourceGroupName' does not match expected pattern '^[-\w._()]+$'.
>   At line:7 char:2
>   +  Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Tag @{BUSINESS_ ...
>   +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmResourceGroup], ValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.SetA
>   zureResourceGroupCmdlet

Comment: `If ($RGName.Tags -eq $null)` - this check doesnt make sense as you are not passing tags, so its always true. as for the error i have no clue, try debugging. or do something like: `$rgname` right before `set-azurermresourcegroup`

Answer (score 0):

First you filtered the content of $RGInfo to only the Resource Group name, you cannot add tags to just the name

```
$RGInfo = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "RG-CRP-D365*" } | Select-Object ResourceGroupName
```

Below syntax should work.

```
$RGInfo = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -like "RG-CRP-D365*" }

ForEach ($RGName in $RGInfo)
{
    If ($RGName.Tags -eq $null)
{ 
Set-AzureRmResourceGroup -ResourceGroupName $RGName.ResourceGroupName -Tag @{BUSINESS_UNIT="CRP"; COST_CENTER="6435" }       
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Spot on!  I knew I was missing some little part of the collection and I completely overlooked that key piece.  The you very much, Hannel

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when importing a list from a CSV file. Turns out the RG names had spaces on it ‍♂️.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).